# Should i encrypt my Unity code for build IOS game?

Tags: c#, android, ios, encryption, unity-game-engine

As we all know ,if the Unity game for android apk most can be reflected to get the Assembly-CSharp.dll  source code. I hear someone say that Unity game for IOS after build had encrypted , if this is true, i have not to take more time to protect my game code . But if this is not realy, what can i do to protect my code on IOS and Android.

Answer (score 2):

To cite the page from the unity manual about Asset protection (bundles)

> [...]our general stance is that if users are determined to extract
>   your assets, they will be able to. - http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/protectingcontent.html

Answer (score 0):

The doc that Minzkraut cites in his answer is about protecting your 3D assets and textures. If you want to protect your code, an easy thing would be to use an objuscation software on your classes. I found one just by writing "obfuscation in unity" on google.

Now, it will make the job of reading your code way more difficult, but it will not encrypt your code so it is not 100% secure.

For most applications, I suppose that there would be no real need to encrypt your code anyway. As for other assets, if someone is truly determined to read your code, he will find a way